# Why is Ubuntu 17.10 locking the screen and asking for password?

Tags: unity, gnome, login, password, privacy

I'm using 17.10 with Gnome. (I upgraded from Unity).

When I close my laptop and reopen I get a duff looking password prompt:

[image: Login picture]

Why is this? There is only one account on this machine and under User I have Automatic Login turned on. Under Privacy I have Screen Lock turned off.

Comment: There has been two autologin settings for many years, one, the autologin under user, the other, lock screen on wakeup or open lid in the power manager. The former is a lightdm/gdm settings, while the latter is related to the screen locker, aka light-locker. In other words, when waking from sleep (or close/open the lid) you are still logged in, but the screen may or may not be locked.

Answer (score 0):

In Gnome there is a setting deep in dconf, which locks the screen when suspended.  This can be set with `dconf-editor` using the setting shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

---

To set is via CLI, open a terminal and enter the command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend false
```