# Problem with lock screen after suspend

Tags: lightdm, login-screen, 18.10, gdm

I'm running Ubuntu 18.10, and I've changed my login screen to lightdm (since I don't like the gdm3 screen), but whenever my laptop suspends, it'll still show the gnome lock screen to log back in. Lightdm works fine with a user lock, log out, and when the computer starts up, but there's something about the waking behavior after suspend that causes it to use the gnome screen. Does anyone know how to edit these settings?

Comment: You could try to disable to gnome lock on suspend:  [https://askubuntu.com/a/981510/283721](https://askubuntu.com/a/981510/283721)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use light-locker.
The light-locker program is a locker that integrates with lightdm to allow session locking.

Answer (score 0):

In Gnome there is a setting deep in dconf, which locks the screen when suspended.  This can be set with `dconf-editor` using the setting shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

---

To set is via CLI, open a terminal and enter the command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend false
```

Comment: Okay, but once I've disabled the gnome lock on suspend, can I enable lightdm to lock on suspend?

Comment: You can certainly give it a try.  I have recently had trouble with gnome-lock-on-suspend, where it refuses to let me log back in (it forces a new instance of my username).